# Question about a site of flash memory performance

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about where to find (site) performance data from flash NAND memory?

> I used some apps from Google Play ("Disk Speed / Performance Test" and
>   "A1 SD Bench") to get some metrics for the internal storage (NAND
>   flash memory) of my tablet.
>
> I got +/- 25 MB/s reading, +/- 9 MB/s writing. This a tablet from 2012.
>
> Is there a site where I can compare this results with similar devices
>   to get a feel if this is normal or not?

Comment: Questions asking where to find a site giving specific information are normally off-topic, on SE.

Answer (score -2):

If your tablet is using Android, Android Enthusiasts may be a good site to go.

Comment: [Android.se] doesn't accept off-site recommendation question, though with certain improvement, the above question might be allowed.